# Scrapy Xpath return empty list

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, wiki, empty-list

It work if Xpath using contains function

```
response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "wikitable sortable")]')
```

However it returns a empty using code below:

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"]')
```

Any explanation about why it return an empty list?

For more information, I'm trying to extract territory rankings table from this site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population as practice.

Comment: I tried these two in terminal and getting different results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  extract territory rankings table easily using only pandas as follows:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population',attrs={'class':'wikitable sortable'})
df = dfs[0]#.to_csv('d.csv')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Rank                  State or territory  ... % of the total U.S. pop.[d]              % of Elec. Coll.
     '20   '10            State or territory  ...                        2010 Ch.2010–2020 % of Elec. Coll.
0    1.0   1.0                    California  ...                      11.91%       –0.11%        
   10.04%
1    2.0   2.0                         Texas  ...                       8.04%        0.66%        
    7.43%
2    3.0   4.0                       Florida  ...                       6.01%        0.42%        
    5.58%
3    4.0   3.0                      New York  ...                       6.19%       –0.17%        
    5.20%
4    5.0   6.0                  Pennsylvania  ...                       4.06%       –0.18%        
    3.53%
5    6.0   5.0                      Illinois  ...                       4.10%       –0.28%        
    3.53%
6    7.0   7.0                          Ohio  ...                       3.69%       –0.17%        
    3.16%
7    8.0   9.0                       Georgia  ...                       3.10%        0.10%        
    2.97%
8    9.0  10.0                North Carolina  ...                       3.05%        0.07%        
    2.97%
9   10.0   8.0                      Michigan  ...                       3.16%       –0.15%        
    2.79%
10  11.0  11.0                    New Jersey  ...                       2.81%       –0.04%        
    2.60%
11  12.0  12.0                      Virginia  ...                       2.56%        0.02%        
    2.42%
12  13.0  13.0                    Washington  ...                       2.15%        0.15%        
    2.23%
13  14.0  16.0                       Arizona  ...                       2.04%        0.09%        
    2.04%
14  15.0  14.0                 Massachusetts  ...                       2.09%        0.00%        
    2.04%
15  16.0  17.0                     Tennessee  ...                       2.03%        0.03%        
    2.04%
16  17.0  15.0                       Indiana  ...                       2.07%       –0.05%        
    2.04%
17  18.0  19.0                      Maryland  ...                       1.85%       –0.00%        
    1.86%
18  19.0  18.0                      Missouri  ...                       1.91%       –0.08%        
    1.86%
19  20.0  20.0                     Wisconsin  ...                       1.82%       –0.06%        
    1.86%
20  21.0  22.0                      Colorado  ...                       1.61%        0.12%        
    1.86%
21  22.0  21.0                     Minnesota  ...                       1.70%        0.01%        
    1.86%
22  23.0  24.0                South Carolina  ...                       1.48%        0.05%        
    1.67%
23  24.0  23.0                       Alabama  ...                       1.53%       –0.03%        
    1.67%
24  25.0  25.0                     Louisiana  ...                       1.45%       –0.06%        
    1.49%
25  26.0  26.0                      Kentucky  ...                       1.39%       –0.04%        
    1.49%
26  27.0  27.0                        Oregon  ...                       1.22%        0.04%        
    1.49%
27  28.0  28.0                      Oklahoma  ...                       1.20%       –0.02%        
    1.30%
28  29.0  30.0                   Connecticut  ...                       1.14%       –0.07%        
    1.30%
29  30.0  29.0                   Puerto Rico  ...                       1.19%       –0.21%        
        —
30  31.0  35.0                          Utah  ...                       0.88%        0.09%        
    1.12%
31  32.0  31.0                          Iowa  ...                       0.97%       –0.02%        
    1.12%
32  33.0  36.0                        Nevada  ...                       0.86%        0.06%        
    1.12%
33  34.0  33.0                      Arkansas  ...                       0.93%       –0.03%        
    1.12%
34  35.0  32.0                   Mississippi  ...                       0.95%       –0.06%        
    1.12%
35  36.0  34.0                        Kansas  ...                       0.91%       –0.04%        
    1.12%
36  37.0  37.0                    New Mexico  ...                       0.66%       –0.03%        
    0.93%
37  38.0  39.0                      Nebraska  ...                       0.58%        0.00%        
    0.93%
38  39.0  40.0                         Idaho  ...                       0.50%        0.05%        
    0.74%
39  40.0  38.0                 West Virginia  ...                       0.59%       –0.06%        
    0.74%
40  41.0  41.0                        Hawaii  ...                       0.43%        0.00%        
    0.74%
41  42.0  43.0                 New Hampshire  ...                       0.42%       –0.01%        
    0.74%
42  43.0  42.0                         Maine  ...                       0.42%       –0.02%        
    0.74%
43  44.0  44.0                  Rhode Island  ...                       0.34%       –0.01%        
    0.74%
44  45.0  45.0                       Montana  ...                       0.32%        0.01%        
    0.74%
45  46.0  46.0                      Delaware  ...                       0.29%        0.01%        
    0.56%
46  47.0  47.0                  South Dakota  ...                       0.26%        0.00%        
    0.56%
47  48.0  49.0                  North Dakota  ...                       0.21%        0.02%        
    0.56%
48  49.0  48.0                        Alaska  ...                       0.23%       –0.01%        
    0.56%
49  50.0  51.0          District of Columbia  ...                       0.19%        0.01%            0.56%
50  51.0  50.0                       Vermont  ...                       0.20%       –0.01%            0.56%
51  52.0  52.0                       Wyoming  ...                       0.18%       –0.01%            0.56%
52  53.0  53.0                       Guam[8]  ...                       0.05%       –0.00%                —
53  54.0  54.0        U.S. Virgin Islands[9]  ...                       0.03%       –0.00%                —
54  55.0  55.0            American Samoa[10]  ...                       0.02%       –0.00%                —
55  56.0  56.0  Northern Mariana Islands[11]  ...                       0.02%       –0.00%                —
56   NaN   NaN      Contiguous United States  ...                      98.03%        0.23%           98.70%
57   NaN   NaN              The fifty states  ...                      98.50%        0.21%           99.44%
58   NaN   NaN     The fifty states and D.C.  ...                      98.69%        0.22%          100.00%
59   NaN   NaN           Total United States  ...                           —            —                —

[60 rows x 16 columns]
```